# Mafia 3 Barclay mills glitch

Tags: mafia-3

I've completed the guns part of Barclay Mills but after a certain point doing the "garbage" cleaners missions there are no longer any missions on the map and I can't talk to Maria. Is there something I'm missing and it's not appearing......... any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Wire Tap a junction box in Barcalay and it should reveal the location of enemies, took me forever to realize this ... hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Apparentlyit's just the mechanic of the mission. You have to wander around the district until you find enemies in this branch of the story, and then kill them and take any loose cash around them or destroy any valuable items. Then you can progress in the story.